# Is there are way using GDrive or Photos resizing pictures before sync/upload?

Tags: applications, sync, photos, google-drive

I'm synchronising all my cam photos to my google drive.
I'm using the photo app on android to upload pictures. There is just one thing that I don't like: I have no option to resize these pictures before the upload. So I have some 2mb pictures and I would like to resize/optimize them before uploading. Cannot find any options, tried also the google drive app, but still the same problem.

I know there are apps to resize pictures, but it´s still annoying to resize every time manually before you sync. I thought there are some options to do that automatically? Funny because some days ago I tested the MS SkyDrive App for Android and there is an option to optimize the pictures. You cannot choose what size you want, but the app resizing all of your pictures that are there for upload pretty well. That´s awesome. Why no such an option for google drive? Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Why not just change the camera settings to take the pictures at lower quality or with a smaller size to start with?

Comment: @DanHulme lowering the megapixel and jpg quality on my cam, is giving me much smaller pictures. That is true, but somehow these pictures are looking really bad. BUT making a pictures with high megapixel and max quality and optimizing them after that with some software to a much smaller size = pictures still looks very good. Dont know why, but this is how it is :(